# Prior Status and Count per patient encounter based on ID and Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following details about customer's appointment history:

```
**CustomerID    Date    Status**
123       1/3/2017  Arrived
123       1/9/2017  Not Arrived
123       2/1/2017  Canceled
123       2/25/2017 Arrived
234       10/8/2016 Arrived
234       11/3/2016 Not Arrived
234       1/8/2017  Not Arrived
234       1/8/2017  Not Arrived
234       1/18/2017 Canceled
```

How would I use SQL to calculate the sum of each appointment status per encounter (arrived, canceled, and not arrived) not including the current encounter? Also, how would I figure out what each customer's prior appointment status was? Linked is a screenshot of what I am trying to produce. Thanks in advance for the help!

[image: Desired Results]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I'm using MSSQL...and thanks for sharing the link and info.

Answer (score 0):

The following query :

```
SELECT appointment.[CustomerID]
      ,appointment.[Date]
      ,appointment.[Status]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.Date < appointment.Date
      AND arrived.Status = 'Arrived') as [ArrivedSum]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.Date < appointment.Date
      AND arrived.Status = 'Canceled') as [CanceledSum]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.Date < appointment.Date
      AND arrived.Status = 'Not Arrived') as [NotArrivedSum]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.Date < appointment.Date) as [TotalAppointments]
      ,CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.Date < appointment.Date) = 0 THEN 'First' ELSE appointment.[Status] END as [LastApptStatus]
  FROM [dbo].[CustomerAppointment] as appointment
  GROUP BY appointment.[CustomerID],appointment.[Date],appointment.[Status]
```

Will give you the results you are waiting for.

Also I would suggest you to **use a technical Primary Key** to avoid entries with the same CustomerID/Date to be forgotten from the calculations. A simple IDENTITY will work great.

With a PK the query would be like this :

```
SELECT appointment.[CustomerID]
      ,appointment.[Date]
      ,appointment.[Status]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.myPK < appointment.myPK
      AND arrived.Status = 'Arrived') as [ArrivedSum]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.myPK < appointment.myPK
      AND arrived.Status = 'Canceled') as [CanceledSum]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.myPK < appointment.myPK
      AND arrived.Status = 'Not Arrived') as [NotArrivedSum]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.myPK < appointment.myPK) as [TotalAppointments]
      ,CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CustomerAppointment] as arrived
      WHERE arrived.CustomerID = appointment.CustomerID
      AND arrived.myPK < appointment.myPK) = 0 THEN 'First' ELSE appointment.[Status] END as [LastApptStatus]
  FROM [dbo].[CustomerAppointment] as appointment
  GROUP BY appointment.[CustomerID],appointment.[Date],appointment.[Status]
```